# GUI guessing game- how to program the guesses correctly

Tags: java

I am new to this website.
Below I have put my code. A LITTLE BACKGROUND ON MY GUI--- this is a guessing game. The computer has thought of a random number between 1 and 100 and the user must try to guess it. When the user inputs a number, the program must tell the user if the number the computer is thinking of is lower or higher or equal to the number the user guessed. The user has 8 tries to guess the number. If the user fails to guess the number within 8 tries, the program will show the user the number and will automatically shut down.
My question is- Can you tell me why the guessing part of the game is not working? I.e. when I enter 100 as the number I want to guess, the program says "Guess higher" and plus, the program does not correctly tell you higher, lower, or equal. THANKS!

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Board extends JPanel{
    private int guessCount;
    private JLabel JLabel1 = new JLabel("Guessing Game");
    private JLabel JLabel2 = new JLabel("The computer will think of a number between");
    private JLabel JLabel3 = new JLabel(" 1 and 100 and you will try to guess it.");
    private JLabel JLabel5 = new JLabel("If you do not get the number within 8 guesses,");
    private JLabel JLabel6 = new JLabel("the program will show you the number and will");
    private JLabel JLabel7 = new JLabel("automatically shut down.");
    private JLabel JLabel4 = new JLabel("Enter your guess: ");
    private JTextField guessInput = new JTextField();
    private JButton submit = new JButton();
     Board()
     {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel subPanelTitle = new JPanel(); 

        JLabel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        JLabel1.setForeground(Color.GREEN); 
        Font font1 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 50);
        JLabel1.setFont(font1);
        JLabel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        JLabel2.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA); 
        Font font2 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18);
        JLabel2.setFont(font2);
        JLabel3.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        JLabel3.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA); 
        Font font3 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18);
        JLabel3.setFont(font3);
        JLabel4.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        JLabel4.setForeground(Color.BLUE); 
        Font font4 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18);
        JLabel4.setFont(font4);
        JLabel5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Font font5 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16);
        JLabel5.setFont(font5);
        JLabel6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel6.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        JLabel6.setFont(font5);
        JLabel7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel7.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        JLabel7.setFont(font5);
        guessInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        submit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        submit.setForeground(Color.RED);
        submit.setText("Submit");
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel1);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel2);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel3);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel5);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel6);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel7);
        subPanelTitle.add(JLabel4);
        subPanelTitle.add(guessInput);
        subPanelTitle.add(submit);
        subPanelTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 350));    
        guessCount = -1;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

        this.add(subPanelTitle,BorderLayout.EAST);

        submit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
     }

        private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            {

            Random generator = new Random();
            int max = 100;
            int min = 1;
            int random = generator.nextInt((max-min+1)-min);
            int getguessInput = 0;


            guessCount++;

            if(guessCount > 7){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are out of guesses. You lose. The number was " + random);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(getguessInput < random){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Guess higher"));
            }
            else if(getguessInput > random){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Guess lower"));
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Congratulations, YOU WIN! " + " It took you " + guessCount + " guesses "));
            }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `private JLabel JLabel1` like WTF you're doing there? Ever heard of naming conventions?

Comment: You generate a new random number whenever the action is triggered, so the advice to guess higher/lower are worthless.

Comment: This is quite a long bit of source code that you have us review here.

Answer (score 4):

```
int getguessInput = 0;
```

is never changed. You're always dealing with a guess of 0, and `guessCount` gets reset as well.

You should make these ints accessible from outside the actionlistener, and make sure that getGuessInput is actually set.

The gory details of this implementation are left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

On every submit, you do the init-routine again and again:

```
        Random generator = new Random();
        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;
        int random = generator.nextInt((max-min+1)-min);
        int getguessInput = 0;
```

This should be done once, e.g. in the class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The Random Number should be generated once, Not everytime the user clicks the button. The entire block of code that generates that needs to be moved out of your button click event.

The `getguessInput` value should be retrieved for each attempt from the users input and not set to 0 on every button click.

My java isn't to sharp but it should be something like this.

```
int getguessinput = Integer.parseInt(guessInput.getText());
```